# Drop and rebuild local indexes on partitioned table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to drop a bitmap index on an existing partitioned table and I want to create a normal local index on same column.  Do i need to create the partitions manually again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to worry about individual partitions.  A LOCAL index will automatically create an index partition for each table partition.

```
--Create partitioned table with local bitmap index.
create table test1(a number, b number)
partition by range(a)
(
    partition p1 values less than (1),
    partition p2 values less than (2)
);
create bitmap index test1_idx on test1(a) local;

--Drop bitmap index.
drop index test1_idx;

--Create a local, btree index.
create index test1_idx on test1(1) local;

--It automatically exists for every partition.
select partition_name from user_ind_partitions where index_name = 'TEST1_IDX';

PARTITION_NAME
--------------
P1
P2
```